# google sheet formula - get column letter by variable?

Tags: google-sheets

Given a formula, eg:

```
= FILTER(matrix!B3:B99, NOT(matrix!C3:C99 = "") )    )
```

Is it possible to pass a variable in place of column B reference? Eg:

```
= FILTER(matrix!$requiredCol3:$requiredCol99, NOT(matrix!C3:C99 = "") )    )
```

where $requiredCol is whatever value is always in A1 for example?

eg, A1=X
formula is now equivilent to:

```
= FILTER(matrix!$X3:$X99, NOT(matrix!C3:C99 = "") )    )
```

Thanks

Comment: If you do such an extended dynamic matrix processing, perhaps MMULT would be better suited to your use? You can cut submatrices out of matrices with it based on variable contents and then process the result further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377), which takes a cell reference as string as (first) parameter. See if this works:

```
= FILTER(INDIRECT("matrix!"&A1&"3:"&A1&"99"), NOT(matrix!C3:C99 = "") )
```

EDIT: if you have the ranges in cells A1 and A2 try

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT(A1), INDIRECT(A2) <>"")
```

Comment: Thanks, this particular solution was quick to impliment. Although I'm having trouble now applying the INDIRECT to the second part of the formula too. I've tried many variations. How can I correctly state NOT(INDIRECT("matrix!"&A1&"3:"&A1&"99"="")) ?

Comment: Or in short, how can this be correctly expressed?   = FILTER(INDIRECT(A1), NOT(INDIRECT(A2)))   where A1 cell content is matrix!B1:B3    and A2 cell content is matrix!C1:C3 = ""           Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that's super!